# Memory leak and weird crashes in android app

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-leaks

I am having an issue with what I believe is a memory leak.

Here are the reasons why:

1. I know that my app takes a lot of RAM, I see it on the graph in Android Studio
2. I sometimes get out of memory exceptions on my phone
3. I did a beta test and some users apps crashes, however some dont. Interestingly enough, a friend with an LG G4 (4 years or so old) is not having any issues and another friend with a Pixel 2 XL couldnt get the app open, it would crash on the main activity.
4. Sometimes when people would close the app and try to use the app switcher, the app switcher itself would crash. But once they would remove my app everything went to normal
5. If they tried to delete the app, it would crash the moment it would come up to the screen. Ex: They would go ahead and go to setting....until they reached the uninstall page. They scrolled down to my app and once the screen registered it was my app settings crashed. And the message read Setting is not responding, or something along those lines.

But here is my issue:

1. I checked all images and none are over 20kb large, as I read the limit is close to 600kb
2. I checked for leaks using the android studio built in function and nothing came up.
3. I changed all context calls to `getApplicationContext()`
4. I used LeakCanary and it only found an 8 mb leak that was happening. And that leak was on a locations class that I believe is androids.

Could that really be the problem?

Another potential issue, I am not sure how dumb I will sound but I havn't been using any threads. I started using them to open new activities for example:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent open = new Intent(MainActivity.this, className);
                    startActivity(open);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

But I havnt seen any difference in performance.

But besides that, everything is working off the main thread.
I am not sure how bad of a habit that is.

Any advice will surely help me!

Thank you!

Comment: A quick workaround would be to add set `largeHeap=true` in your manifest. Have you tried this?

Comment: you have to learn more !! its really a very **broad** question !!

Comment: @Sagar yes I have tried this, thank you though

Comment: @SantanuSur Can you point me in the right direction? Is multi threading a solution? What are my problems?

Comment: "I am not sure, how bad of habit that is" — that's indeed a dumb habit. You don't need to use Handler there, just invoke startActivity from the background thread. It is actually safe, because startActivity is a Binder call into ActivityManager. You probably should not do it with startActivityForResult, because it may modify Activity state. Either way, starting Activities from separate thread is largely pointless — your user won't notice difference, because your app is going to be hidden either way. Regarding leaks in Android classes — this is normal. But you have to post  details of leak here!

Comment: Why you need another thread to start new activity?

Comment: @nhoxbypass I am not sure, i just figured it was a good idea. is that not true?

Comment: @EdonFreiner it's useless, because Activity will run on main thread